# Subarray based on particular user choice dimension number

Tags: matlab

Say, I have a 3D array of dimensions `n x m x p` and i want a subarray based on particular user choice dimension number.

For example: **A** is a 3D array `n x m x p`

`function sub_A = subset(A,dim)

 if subset(A,1) ->  subset gives sub_A 1 x m x p
 if subset(A,2) ->  subset gives sub_A m x 1 x p
 if subset(A,3) ->  subset gives sub_A m x n x 1`

Comment: How do you know *which* index to use on the specified dimension? For example for `subset(A, 1)` is it `A(1,:,:)` or `A(2,:,:)`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a cell array of indexes and use [a comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) with `{:}` indexing to index into your matrix. Note that you also need to provide the index to use along the specified dimension otherwise it's not clear which "slice" to use along that dimension.

```
function result = subset(A, dim, index)
    % Create the subscript to use for each dimension. We use ':' for all except
    % for the specified subset dimension we use the provided index
    inds = repmat({':'}, 1, ndims(A));
    inds{dim} = index;

    % Now perform the indexing using subsref and substruct
    result = A(inds{:});
end
```

And you could use it like the following:

```
A = rand(4,5,3);

B = subset(A, 1, 1);
size(B)
%   1   5   3

C = subset(A, 2, 1);
size(C)
%   4   1   3

D = subset(A, 3, 1);
size(D)
%   4   5
```

Or you can even specify multiple indexes along that specified dimension

```
E = subset(A, 1, [1 3]);
size(E)
%   2   5   3
```

Comment: Why not `A(inds{:})` instead of `subsref(A, substruct('()', inds));`?

Comment: @LuisMendo Good point! I keep forgetting that you can use a literally `':'` outside of `substruct`